# Print histogram in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, histogram

I have a word length_of_word | repetitions dictionary and I want to make a histogram of that like the one in link below using only python built in functions no numpy or anything like it.

http://dev.collabshot.com/show/723400/

Please help me out at least with some pointers.

Comment: You're going to at the very least have to provide an example of your input and your expected output. Say, 5 entries from the dictionary and the corresponding histogram.

Comment: You probably should have mentioned that this is part of the final exam from Oreilly's Python 1 class. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you must have a `dict` that looks like this one, right ?

```
>>> d = {1:1, 2:10, 3:10, 4:6, 5:5, 6:4, 7:2, 8:1}
>>> d
{1: 1, 2: 10, 3: 10, 4: 6, 5: 5, 6: 4, 7: 2, 8: 1}
```

If so, I have a function that does the trick:

```
>>> def histo(dict_words):
    # Get max values, plus delta to ease display
    x_max = max(dict_words.keys()) + 2
    y_max = max(dict_words.values()) + 2
    # print line per line
    print '^'
    for j in range(y_max, 0, -1):
        s = '|'
        for i in range(1, x_max):
            if i in dict_words.keys() and dict_words[i] >= j:
                s += '***'
            else:
                s += '   '
        print s
    # print x axis
    s = '+'
    for i in range(1, x_max):
        s += '---'
    s += '>'
    print s
    # print indexes
    s = ' '
    for i in range(1, x_max):
        s += ' %d ' % i
    print s


>>> histo(d)
^
|                           
|                           
|   ******                  
|   ******                  
|   ******                  
|   ******                  
|   *********               
|   ************            
|   ***************         
|   ***************         
|   ******************      
|************************   
+--------------------------->
  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 
>>>
```

Ok, there's a little more work to display values on the left and to format correctly numbers greater than 10 not to have shift in indexes, but I think it's a good start :-)